# How can I set the font for the selected element in a UISegmentedControl?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to use different fonts for the selected and un-selected segments in a UISegmentedControl. I can set the font for the normal segments, but I can't seem to set the font for the selected segment. Here's my code:

```
    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
                      [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold"
                                      size:[UIFont buttonFontSize]]
                forKey:UITextAttributeFont];
[playerNumber setTitleTextAttributes:attributes
                            forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

If I change to `UIControlStateNormal`, all the segments are styled. However, I just want to style the highlighted/selected segment. (`UIControlStateSelected` doesn't work either.)

(There are a few similar StackOverflow questions, but I couldn't find an answer that solved my issue.)

What am I doing wrong or can't it be done at all?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the font on segment select, rather than trying to predefine the selectedState font to be used for all segments? Something like the following (untested):

```
int segmentIndex = self.mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;
if (segmentIndex == 0)
{
    [self.mySegmentedControl setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12] forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [self.mySegmentedControl setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10] forSegmentAtIndex:1];        
}
else if (segmentIndex == 1)
{
    [self.mySegmentedControl setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10] forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [self.mySegmentedControl setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12] forSegmentAtIndex:1]; 
}
```

I do something along these lines in one of my apps now, but it is using images for the segments.

Answer (score 0):

I met this issue today, I believe this is an iOS's bug.

Here is my hack.

```
@interface TFSegmentedControl : UISegmentedControl

@end

#import "TFSegmentedControl.h"

@implementation TFSegmentedControl
{
    BOOL layoutedOnce;
}

- (void)updateSelectedStyle
{
    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
        BOOL selected = [[view valueForKey:@"selected"] boolValue];
        for (UILabel *label in view.subviews) {
            if ([label isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
                UIFont *font = [self titleTextAttributesForState:UIControlStateNormal][UITextAttributeFont];
                if (selected) {
                    UIFont *_font = [self titleTextAttributesForState:UIControlStateSelected][UITextAttributeFont];
                    if (_font) font = _font;
                }
                if (font != label.font) {
                    label.font = font;
                    CGRect frame = label.frame;
                    frame.size = [label.text sizeWithFont:font];
                    label.frame = frame;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)sendActionsForControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents
{
    [self updateSelectedStyle];
    [super sendActionsForControlEvents:controlEvents];
}

- (void)setSelectedSegmentIndex:(NSInteger)selectedSegmentIndex
{
    [super setSelectedSegmentIndex:selectedSegmentIndex];
    [self updateSelectedStyle];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    if (!layoutedOnce) {
        layoutedOnce = YES;
        [self updateSelectedStyle];
    }
}

@end
```